# Make a list element of multiple types in python

Tags: python, list

I want to make a list element that takes values from multiple types of variables.
I tried to do like this but it gives the error:
cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

```
name = "John"
age = 12
data = name + age
```

I want a list like this

> data = [('John', 12)]

Comment: When you wrote `data = [('John', 12)]`, did that give you what you wanted?

Comment: I want take them from a variable

Answer (score 4):

Just pack them into a tuple and create a list:

```
data = [(name, age)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just to that :D

```
test = [None]*2

test[0] = "TEST"
test[1] = 25

print(test)

Gives:
['TEST',25]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see the problem since lists are capable of storing multiple types.

However, since you seem to want a list of names linked to age, you should look up dictionaries.

```
data = {'John':12 , 'Marie':14}
```

In this example data is a dictionary, it's like a list but instead of calling items like `data[1]` you can call `data['Marie']`and it will return you Marie's age (in this case).

If you want more information about dictionaries I suggest you look it up.

Comment: My need is a bit different from dictionaries, I use this list to put data to the sqlite query

Answer (score 0):

You can just give the type for each item you need, even if you have more list elements, like here:

```
list = [int(list[0]),float(list[1]), int(list[2]), float(list[3])]
```